# jQuery / sessionStorage: flicker effect on hidden element, hidden programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery

When the jQuery locates the sessionStorage entry, it adds a new class to my div. The actual code works fine, however each time i refresh the page the div first renders as a flicker, and then disappears. This is obviously due to the declaration of the function (ie div is loading before the function call, as expected).

Without moving the function and jquery reference to the head, is it possible to avoid this flicker effect?

Thanks

```
<body>

<div class="browser-warning">
    Browser not supported..
</div>


<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if (sessionStorage.getItem("browser-warningHidden") != null) {
            $(".browser-warning").addClass("is-hidden");
        }
    });
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Moving to the head won't matter because it's in a `document.ready` call. Removing that after moving to the head won't work either because the div won't be loaded yet, so it won't be found. Showing it upon getting the sessionStorage is your best bet.

Comment: I would also need to move the jquery library reference to the head which I don't want to do

Comment: Out of curiosity, what browsers aren't you supporting? Is it just older versions?

Comment: In a configuration file we list ie 6, 7 and 8 as unsupported. It'll grow over time

Comment: I'd say for now, if it's just those browsers, you could use a conditional comment to show the div. You could use the sessionStorage as a backup.

Comment: One thing I would suggest at least trying; add this show/hide call inside of `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded')`. JQuery probably involves a quarter-second of overhead without caching, and if you could write this function with basic JavaScript, it might operate quickly enough to be invisible.

Comment: @brouxhaha That was one of the ideas we initially had, but working at enterprise level we wanted something that could scale

Comment: @Katana314 I believe we will encounter issues with IE 6/7 using addEventListener?

Comment: @Oblivy Ahh, I didn't read close enough into the example to see this is about the non-supported browsers. Is there any chance of detecting features after-load, and then showing the warning based on that instead of having it non-hidden from the get-go? You could also have the same error block inside of a `<noscript>` tag.

Comment: @Katana314 the browser detection is actually done server side. It's done on the server as we have a.config listing the unsupported browsers in xml format. The mvc view then looks through the config keys. At this point we can then decide whether or not to render the partial view (browser warning). The ultimate idea is to allow for users to browse with the banner still there, or dismiss it.  If it was up to me I'd forget the dismissing function altogether so the constant reminder to upgrade is there! No pity for ie users :)

Comment: @Katana314 thanks for your help. I'll discuss further in our scrum daily tomorrow and update my question, hopefully with an answer!

Answer (score 1):

Just do the opposite effect, hide the message first and show it if you need to (instead of showing it first, and hiding it if you need to):

```
<body>

<div style="display: none;" class="browser-warning">
    Browser not supported..
</div>


<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if (sessionStorage.getItem("browser-warningHidden") == null) {
            $(".browser-warning").show();
        }
    });
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: My first thought too, but then on each page load the dom loads up first, and then the div element last, on page loads where the session item does exist

Comment: Huh? I'm not sure if I follow the apparent problems with this approach. This div is part of the dom, so it will load before the ready function runs.